# UUID of iPhone Device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am making a Bluetooth chat app using CoreBluetooth, for which I require the UUID of the device.

I tried out the following ways: https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2018/04/04/how-to-find-your-device-id-uuid-for-iphone-development/

But with this, I am getting UDID not UUID.

```
let WR_UUID = CBUUID(string: "e67e26af6a591f11d3ff186acd1765b2373a2131")
let WR_PROPERTIES: CBCharacteristicProperties = .write
let WR_PERMISSIONS: CBAttributePermissions = .writeable
```

This is how my code looks, with UDID. It throwing the following error: *String e67e26af6a591f11d3ff186acd1765b2373a2131 does not represent a valid UUID'*

How do I get a valid UUID of the device?

Comment: Why do you think you need the UUID of the device?  The `identifier` that Core Bluetooth returns for a peripheral is unique for that peripheral/central pair.  It is not something you can use on another central with the same peripheral.  You use `CBUUID`s to advertise and discover services in Core Bluetooth

Comment: Because I want to connect to a specific device.

Comment: Also if that's the case then, what value should I put here, in these two statements. ` let serialService = CBMutableService(type: <#T##CBUUID#>, primary: true)
            let writeCharacteristics = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: <#T##CBUUID#>, properties: .write, value: nil, permissions: .writeable) `

Comment: Any UUID you like; You can just generate two by typing `uuidgen` on the command line